# Anaconda Spyder - Class Attributes Autocompletion

Tags: python, class, anaconda, attributes, spyder

I have a couple of Classes defined.
Both of these classes take a json file as input, and extract the data into a class instance, and places them into a dictionary.

So all of my EmployeeProfile instances are stored in a dictionary called SP, with the employees email as the key, and the class instance as the value.

All of my RiskProfile instances are stored in a dictionary called RISKS, with the risk_ID as the key and the class instance as the value.

```
class EmployeeProfile:
    def __init__(self, profile):
        self.displayname = profile.get('displayName')
        self.email = profile.get('email')
        self.firstname = profile.get('firstName')
        self.surname = profile.get('surname')
        self.fullname = profile.get('fullName')
        self.costcode = profile.get('work').get('custom')\
            .get('Cost Category_t9HHc')
        self.title = profile.get('work').get('title')
        self.department = profile.get('work').get('department')
        self.city = profile.get('work').get('site')
        self.id = profile.get('work').get('employeeIdInCompany')
        self.manageremail = ''
        self.costline = 'N/A'
        self.groups = {}
        self.attest = {}
```

```
class RiskProfile:
    def __init__(self, risk_profile):
        self.ID = risk_profile.get('ID')
        self.key = risk_profile.get('Key')
        self.name = risk_profile.get('Name')
        self.description = risk_profile.get('Description', '')
        self.owner = risk_profile.get("Owner_DisplayName")
        self.assignedto = risk_profile.get("AssignedTo_DisplayName")
        self.email = None
        self.costline = ''
        self.notes = ''
        self.assessmentlevel = int(risk_profile.get("AssessmentLevel"))
        self.rating = ''
        self.workflow = risk_profile.get('WorkflowState')
```

Now when I do something like:

```
for profile in SP:
    print(SP[profile].{here i see the attribute of the class instance})
```

So I can see a selection of the attributes I may want to print or change etc...

```
print(SP[profile].department)
```

or

```
print(SP[profile].name)
```

However when I do the same for RiskProfile instances I do not get the list of attributes.
If I enter them manually my code still works, but does anyone know why this is not working the same way?

```
for profile in RISKS:
    print(RISK[profile].{I never get a list of attributes})
```

I use Anaconda with Spyder.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking a question about auto-completion, which is going to be specific to the editor/IDE you're using.

Comment: Does it work if you try it on a single `RiskProfile` instance not accessed through a dict?

Comment: sorry for the bad edits by me, I totally misinterpreted the question. Feel free to change it back if I edited something without improvement

Comment: That's a great suggestion @Iguananaut, first I tried this will a single RiskProfile which worked as it should. Then I dumped all of the profiles into a list and again it worked as it should.

So it looks like the issue is when I dump the profiles into a dictionary.
I wonder if there is a issue with the key name?

All of my Key's are named like this:
R-378
R-379
R-380
R-381
R-382
R-383
R-384
R-385
R-386

I'll try removing the hyphen and see what results I get....

Comment: I don't think it would have anything to do with the key names.  That's not something a type checker would know what to do with or care about.  What would be more important is if all the keys are the same types (string) and the values are the same types as well.  Otherwise it can't meaningfully infer anything about an arbitrary value from the dictionary.

Comment: @Iguananaut, I checked all of my class instances and they are all the same. Interestingly when I dump all of the class instances into a list I have no issues at all, it's only when I dump them into a dictionary it seems to stop working.

Comment: Interestingly, when I import the RiskProfle class into my main.py and have the list or dictionary assigned to variable, I an not able to use spyder to view the variable through the variable explorer. When I try to do this SPyder crashes..